# Scaling for mixed data and reverse transform

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, ordinal-data, mixed-type-data, feature-scaling

I have mixed type data (numerical, one hot encoded, ordinal). My data also has outliers. I am trying to scale them using a StandardScaler from sklearn, but I also need to revese transform the test data. Is it ok to just use the reverse transform from sklearn on the non fitted (test) data? I am concerned with the ordinal as I will not be getting integers any more. Do you have any suggestions for this case?